# Identify latency problems to gaming server

Tags: networking, ping, gaming, traceroute, latency

I am playing an online game where the server is physically located in the same city (~10km=6miles). I have cabled internet with WiFi and have a ping around 170-200ms with severe spikes. From my phone 5G the latency seems to be the same. At my friend's house, under a different ISP, the ping is 9ms without any spikes.

I need help in identifying whether the issue is from my ISP, my WiFi set-up, or the game server itself. That my friend has a lower ping seems to indicate that it is my ISP. If so I need to contact my ISP and tell them what is wrong. The game has several local servers with similar results.

**Note**: the game runs on my Android Phone using 5.2GHz WiFi band. Tradert + PingPlotter is from my older laptop using the 2.4GHz WiFi band. Although similar ping test on my phone yields the same 170-200ms ping.

**Traceroute from me to 92.223.86.86 using PingPlotter:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Traceroute from 3rd party Singapore server to 92.223.86.86**
[1ms] (https://www.ip2location.com/free/traceroute)
[image]

**Geoping from 3rd party Singapore server to 92.223.86.86**
[3ms] (GeoPing in Android PingTools)
[image]

**CABLED sample as requested:**
[image]

**A new WiFi sample taken for comparison:**
[image]
We can see that the cabled one still has 170 ms ping to destination. However, the amount of package loss is greatly reduced ( PL% columns and the red bars)

**Graph using 3rd party server and VPN**

VPN (SG): 84.17.39.173

3rdParty (SG): 185.128.24.225

Target (SG): 92.223.86.86

[image]
I suppose pinging from my VPN means that it first goes from ME to VPN.

ME <-> VPN traceroute seems to hop via Hong-Kong (SG<-> HK <-> SG).

**Also posted here:**
https://linustechtips.com/topic/1528507-identify-latency-problems-to-game-server/

Comment: Maybe its your wifi. Can you test with cabke fir comparison

Comment: Can you try a VPN? That might be able to force the route in a different direction and avoid the bad hops you are seeing.

Comment: @Mokubai good idea, but I would have to money up first. I did traceroute from several global servers (geo-ping), most SG ones to destination give <1ms. Like why on earth does my own traffic head for Uranus and back. ^^

Comment: Your newly-added picture is very odd. I can't even ping my own gateway in under 1ms, let alone a remote node.  Can't format this properly in comments, sorry…  1  tetsserver (192.168.0.1)  2.198 ms  1.704 ms  1.933 ms
 2  * * *
 3  hari-core-2a-ae37-0.network.virginmedia.net (82.2.243.57)  12.182 ms  10.535 ms  16.004 ms [I get 250ms to gcore.lu, but I **am** on the other side of the world to it.]

Comment: @Tetsujin, added more information above, the traceroute from 3rd party server and a new geo ping

Comment: Turns out the game server hosting company has a traceroute tool.
https://lg.gcore.lu/
REGION: Asia & Pacific, ROUTER: Singapore
IP: 116.15.1.21 (me) we get 180ms, just what I observe pinging the specific game server.

Comment: I'm on the same ISP - and I'm getting the same traceroute. I'm on a wired connection - the non answer is *sometimes* singtel's routing is strange. . @Tetsujin I'm getting sub 1ms to the singtel supplied ONR on a wired connection so its possible.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - ah, OK. I'm nearly 2ms from my gateway, 12ms to the first major node, but then about 30 to anything else in the EU. 100ms minimum to the US. [You used to be able to ask SpeedTest to check to specific nodes, with saved URLs, which we used a lot for an online game I used to do support for. They unfortunately dropped that service a few years ago.]

Comment: We're a much smaller country 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved [here](https://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/threads/singtel-identify-latency-problems-to-sg-game-server-is-st-routing-to-the-moon.6942466/)

The traffic from the game server back to me is routed via San Jose in the US, hence the 180ms latency. The reason is that, as opposed to all other ISPs in SG, my ISP does not peer (openly) on Singapore Internet Exchange (SGIX), hence the traffic cannot enter my ISP without peering elsewhere instead, in this case in the USA. The solution is to change ISP to one that peers openly.

Answer (score 1):

Your traceroute shows that not only is the large increase in ping times well outside your control, between asianet & gcore, but also that those two locations are many thousands of miles apart - Singapore to Luxembourg.
*OK - that's odd… domain name says .lu, which is Luxembourg, but the IP address shows as actually being in Singapore.*
Still, that doesn't change the thrust of the answer, which is that it's well outside your control.

Your first outside hop, to singnet is only 10ms - that's the only bit your ISP is responsible for. The rest neither you nor they can do anything about.

Comment: Thanks, that's odd though, as as you say I thought it was in Singapore. Any idea why at my friend's place (2 km away) the ping is 9ms?  It seems it is not routed to LU there then. Maybe difficult to know without the same test there. It feels like his ISP has some higher priority than mine then.

Comment: The thing is, you cannot dictate the route it will take. You won't even necessarily get the same route twice if you run it again. Plus, the game itself may not take the same route. Each route is assigned on the fly. You could test from your friend's if their route picks something very different. Either way, there's absolutely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Apart from changing to the same ISP as him I assume.. So I have never noticed a ping lower than 170 ms, like ever (dozens of hours, hundreds of gaming sessions), while at my friend's I got 9ms in all 20 sessions (tried switching off WiFi to 5G mobile data changed the ping to 170ms). So it is a questions if I should change ISP, or move in to my friend's house ;) (the hosting company declined to help out, but I might also be able to provide info to the game devs)

Comment: The fact that the hostname has a country code of ".lu" by no means says that it must be physically located in Luxemburg. The IP is owned by Gcore which is a Content Distribution Network company headquartered in Luxemburg but operating worldwide.

Comment: What you _can_ do is use a nearby VPN server; the route from you to the VPN host and from there to the game server may very well be different from the direct one.

Comment: @StarCat - makes sense. I'd never heard of them before.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, updated the post with two such scenarios, one traceroute and one geoping

Comment: @u1686_grawity, sorry was using from 3rd party server, not via 3rd party server (VPN).

Comment: @u1686_grawity: see hand drawn graph